# Pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is my code:

```
import os 
import pandas as pd

path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(f, usecols = ['A','B','C','D','E'])
    df = df.append(data)
```

I get the traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\dbhadra\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1134, in _validate_usecols_names
    "columns expected but not found: {missing}".format(missing=missing)

ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['B', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'D']
```

I've used a similar command for `read_excel` before and it works. Do I need to include the `sep/engine` arguments? I don't see why. Also, can I use `usecol = 'A:E'` as in read_excel? The csv files are quite vanilla. No tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel you have the main column naming (A-Z, AA-ZZ...). In CSV you haven't it. `usecols` is the list of columns according to their headers (in the first line). If you have no headers in your CSV file, just remove `usecols`, you can delete these columns later. Or you can specify columns as integers (like `usecols=(1, 3, 7)` instead of `usecols=(A, C, F)`. If you have headers, write their names in `usecols`.

> `usecols : list-like or callable, optional`
>
> Return a subset of the columns. If list-like, all elements must either be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or strings that correspond to column names provided either by the user in names or inferred from the document header row(s). For example, a valid list-like usecols parameter would be `[0, 1, 2]` or `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`. Element order is ignored, so `usecols=[0, 1]` is the same as `[1, 0]`. To instantiate a DataFrame from data with element order preserved use `pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['foo', 'bar']]` for columns in `['foo', 'bar']` order or `pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['bar', 'foo']]` for `['bar', 'foo']` order.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to True. An example of a valid callable argument would be `lambda x: x.upper()` in `['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']`. Using this parameter results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the docs for pandas.read_csv and pandas.read_excel

for `read_csv()`:

> u**secols : list-like or callable, optional**
>
> Return a subset of the columns. If list-like, **all elements must either be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or strings that correspond to column names provided either by the user in names or inferred from the document header row(s).** For example, a valid list-like usecols parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

and for `read_excel()`

> **usecols : int, str, list-like, or callable default None**
>
> Return a subset of the columns. * If None, then parse all columns. * If int, then indicates last column to be parsed.
>
> Deprecated since version 0.24.0: Pass in a list of int instead from 0 to usecols inclusive.
>
> If str, then indicates comma separated list of Excel column letters and column ranges (e.g. “A:E” or “A,C,E:F”). Ranges are inclusive of both sides.
>
> If list of int, then indicates list of column numbers to be parsed.
>
> If list of string, then indicates list of column names to be parsed.

so in your case pass either column names from header or list of integers (column indexes)